# How would code this in NN?

Tags: machine-learning, rnn, cnn, lstm

[image: Left is input and right is output both 5 by 5 grids- also note that rows represent time, so as time goes by there are some residual effects from previous times on next time steps - also assume we have many sets of these inputs outputs to train this NN - the effects of input may impact several next outputs - .]

is there any python code already available to do this? - I would appreciate if you can elaborate on coding of this problem as I am new to NN.

Comment: I am not sure if figure captions shows up or not, so I am writing my question here again. I have a set of inputs(left column) and outputs (right column) in a 5 by 5 grid. as you can see the output has some delay plus it impacts next few time steps. ( rows represent time). What would be the best approach to code this in NN assuming I have many sets of this input/output data? is there any Python code already available to do this? I do apologize for this, but I am new to NN, so as much as you can please elaborate even add lines of code on how would you solve this.  Thank you.

Comment: Please note that I have normalized input and out values between 0 and 1 and they are values in between and depending on the value of input response is stronger or weaker in the output.

Comment: Is every pixel represented by a RBG triplet?

Comment: @mapto yes, these are values between 0 and 1 that I have plotted using (matshow). I believe there should be a way to extract their RBG triplet. Or i can plot them in gery scale and get their corresponding value.